# State Income Tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, alabama

In 2012, my husband and I filed an amended state income tax.  This year we received a letter stating that we never filed. I appealed their decision, sent in proof of filing and was denied because we were 3 days late in filing the appeal.  We now have to pay over $3,000.  Is there a way I will be able to be refunded this money?

Comment: My first step would be to talk to a tax attorney.